Call an API with Glue: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
I am currently trying to call an API using python shell in AWS glue, we are using requests library to first authenticate to an API then make some get requests to different endpoints. THe code looks something like this
import requests

def make_requests(endpoints):
    # Create a session object
    with requests.Session() as session:
        # Loop through the dictionary of endpoints
        for endpoint in endpoints:
            url = endpoint.get('url')
            params = endpoint.get('params', {})  # Default to an empty dict if params not provided
            
            try:
                # Make the GET request
                response = session.get(url, params=params)
                response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad responses (4xx or 5xx)

                # Process the response (you can modify this as needed)
                print(f"Response from {url}:")
                print(response.text)  

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                # Handle any exceptions (e.g., connection errors, timeouts, etc.)
                print(f"Error occurred while making request to {url}: {e}")

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    endpoints_dict = [
        {
            'url': 'https://api.example.com/endpoint1',
            'params': {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}
        },
        {
            'url': 'https://api.example.com/endpoint2',
            'params': {'paramA': 'valueA'}
        },
        {
            'url': 'https://api.example.com/endpoint3',
            'params': {'paramA': 'valueA'}
        }
    ]

    make_requests(endpoints_dict)

However intermittently we are getting a
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdaafa0c910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

There doesn't seem to be a pattern, it works sometimes for all endpoints, will occasionally fail at different points. ANy ideas?
